# Product of objects are isomorphic - help with a diagram

Tags: category-theory

I am reading "Topoi - The Categorial Analysis Of Logic" by Robert Goldblatt, but I'm struggling with a detail - to quote:

"Notice that we said *a* product of $a$ and $b$, not *the product* . This is because $a \times b$ is only defined up to isomorphism. For suppose $(p \colon d \rightarrow a, q \colon d \rightarrow b)$ also satisfies the definition of "a product of $a \times b$" and consider the diagram:

[image]

..."

Now, I get most of it, but how do I see that $\left\langle pr_a,pr_b \right\rangle$ goes from $a \times b$ to $d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a overloading of the operator $\langle {-},{-} \rangle$ here.

The first one in the instance $\langle p,q \rangle$ comes from the natural isomorphism
$$ \hom(-,a) \times \hom(-,b) \underset\simeq{\overset{\langle-,-\rangle} \to} \hom(-,a\times b) $$
given by the fact that $a\times b$ is a product of $a$ and $b$.

The second one in the instance $\langle \mathrm{pr}_a,\mathrm{pr}_b \rangle$ comes from the natural isomorphism
$$ \hom(-,a) \times \hom(-,b) \underset\simeq{\overset{\langle-,-\rangle} \to} \hom(-,d) $$
given by the fact that $d$ is a product of $a$ and $b$.

To be perfectly rigorous, the authors should have subscripted each instance: $\langle p, q \rangle_{(a\times b,\mathrm{pr}_a,,\mathrm{pr}_b)}$ and $\langle \mathrm{pr}_a,\mathrm{pr}_b \rangle_{(d, p, q)}$. But it is heavy and usually the subscript is inferable from context. The same thing appears in many area of mathematics: for example we use the same (absence of) symbol for the multiplication of many many groups.

Comment: Natural isomorphism, eh? I've heard about them, but it is unfortunate that they are used before they have been introduced :-)

Comment: @j4nd3r53n Sorry I don't have the book at hand to check the order in which the concepts are introduced. But actually you don't need to know what it is to understand the answer, all you need to understand is that a product is a triplet $(x,f,g)$ with a universal property that implies in particular a map $\langle-,-\rangle: \hom(-,a) \times \hom(-,b) \to \hom(-,x)$ and that notation is overloaded in the excerpt that you quote.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't be sarcastic. I really do appreciate your help, and this book is actually very good. I just have a tendency of picking at every little detail. I don't feel I understand things otherwise.